# one wordpress loop with different style outputs

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to style the first post differently than the rest. It's for a "featured" section on index.php

```
<?php
$count = 0;
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
$count++;
if ( $count == 1 ) : ?>

    <div class="big">

        <div class="details">
        <a class="cat" href="#">nike</a>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><p><?php the_title(); ?></p></a>
        <ul class="stats">
        <li class="icon-calendar"><?php the_time('m.d.Y') ?></li>
        <li class="icon-eye"><?php if(function_exists('the_views')) { the_views(); } ?></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <?php echo get_first_inserted_image(); ?>

    </div>

<?php else : ?>

    <div class="small">

        <div class="holder">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_first_inserted_image(); ?></a>
          <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
        </div>    

    </div>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

the above code does not seem to work as nothing is showing up. I would also like to expand on this to show only 4 random posts from the last 7 days. Any guidance is appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: Nothing is showing up because you've passed `$args` to the query without defining `$args`...

Answer (score 0):

this got it done

```
<?php

// WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'showposts' => 5,
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after' => '1 week ago'
        )
    )

);


$count = 0;
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
$count++;
if ( $count == 1 ) : ?>

    <div class="big">

        <div class="details">
        <a class="cat" href="#">nike</a>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><p><?php the_title(); ?></p></a>
        <ul class="stats">
        <li class="icon-calendar"><?php the_time('m.d.Y') ?></li>
        <li class="icon-eye"><?php if(function_exists('the_views')) { the_views(); } ?></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_first_inserted_image(); ?></a>

    </div>

<?php else : ?>

    <div class="small">

        <div class="holder">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_first_inserted_image(); ?></a>
          <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
        </div>    

    </div>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```